# Including google bigquery python lib in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python script that starts as follows:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

This package is installed with:

```
pip install google-cloud-bigquery --upgrade
```

Im under the impression that pyinstaller should find all of the required packages and install them but when I run the created .exe on windows or executable on mac, I get the error message:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Here is my .spec file, please tell me where I can put `google-cloud-core` so that the correct packages are installed.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['tests.py'],
         pathex=['/Users/daniellee/Development/alice-connectors/aconn'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='tests',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how I got it to work.

Use a hook file, named `hook-google.cloud.bigquery` that contains:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('google-cloud-bigquery')
datas += copy_metadata('google-cloud-core')
```

Then add the path to this hook file to your .spec file.

```
 ...
 hookspath=['/Users/joesoap/Development/project/hooks']
 ...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Absolute hero. Nice one

Comment: I also found that the hook file must also end with the .py suffix in order to be picked up.